# Thinkpad T420 3g modem

Tags: thinkpad, modem, mobile-broadband, 3g

I have been trying to connect to 3G using my data sim card on ubuntu.
lssub return this:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0083 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical  Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b221 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd integrated camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The bios is showing WWAN and it is enabled.  I still cannot find the 3G modem. In my network manager I can get mobile broadband setup however cant find it anywhere in tty. I believe the card is Ericsson f5521gw but cannot find any trace to it although I am sure it is enabled but I think i need the driver cant find this anywhere.

It will be really great if anyone can help with this. I followed several forum entries to try to get it work , I have installed wvdial and sakis3g

Any help will be great. 
Cheers